# onRefresh webview - как узнать url

Tags: android

в MainActivity.java стоит

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            aswm_view(url, false);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

как мне определить `url`, чтобы перезагружалась текущая страница сайта?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем узнавать, используйте обыкновенный `reload()`

> void reload ()
>   Reloads the current URL.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#reload()

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = aswm_view.getUrl();
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl())